# An issue in selecting multiple images while using angular-multiple-selection for AnguarJS

Tags: angularjs

I am actually stuck in a problem while using angular-multiple-selection [Module NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-multiple-selection). I am successfully able to select multiple images. But I have failed in selecting images by dragging (which is possible and shown in both the demos of the module [Demo Link](http://maxazan.github.io/angular-multiple-selection/)

I am actually trying out the module in a ng-repeat.

```
.row(multiple-selection-zone='')
    .col-lg-2.col-md-2(multiple-selection-item='', ng-class="{'selecting': isSelecting ,'selected': isSelected}" ng-repeat="product in products track by $index")
        img(src="{{product.image ? product.image : product.s3Image}}")
```

and its CSS is:

```
style.
    .selected {
        background-color: green !important;
    }
    .selecting {
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }
    img {
        height: 200px;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 500px;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

I am unable to find where to place the multiple-selection-zone and multiple-selection-item. I've tried various combinations of putting them inside the row, col and img. I've even tried to match my code with that of the demo's through Inspect Element. But there was no positive result.

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: @Programmer21 Can you please help me resolve this? Or can you please tell me whom can I get in touch with?

Comment: sure! i will help you bro!

Comment: what version of angular you are using?

Comment: Angular 1.6.4 bro!

Comment: @Programmer21 Bro, the edit that you've suggested regarding the indentation isn't working. So, had to revert it back!

Comment: no problem!  we are here to help each other https://jsfiddle.net/billajo21/6L0whL5t/  this will help you

Comment: I have seen your answer on the JSFiddle. Dude, I am actually using angular-multipe-selection. Can you please look into that module. I've attached the link in the question itself. Thanks for your fiddle!